# Logitech C615 on Macbook Air (Mac OSX 10.8.2)

Tags: macos, webcam

I have been looking into buying a web cam to serve as a document camera.  I have read a lot of conflicting reviews on the Logitech C615. Does anyone know if the webcam is compatible with my OS?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "yes". I have Mountain Lion and just received my C615. I'm able to record photos and movies, using the provided LWS software, and play them back via QuickTime. Cannot speak for other apps. Be aware that many of the features (e.g., zoom) that are available on Windows are not (currently) available on the Mac.